# Retrieving variable out of event handler scope

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, websocket

Currently working on a project using Websockets and node.js. At the moment I'm generating some random numbers and sending them to a client every half second.

```
    var array = [];

wss.on("connection", function (ws) {
    setInterval(function () {
        var data  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;    //create a random whole number between 1-100
        var msg = JSON.stringify(data);                     //convert data to JSON string
        ws.send(msg);                                       //send JSON string to client
    }, 500);


})
```

However now I would like to every minute store the value at that minute into a database. I don't want nest my inserts to mongodb in the `wss.on` function as it seems to be messy. Is there a way for me to get the value of `data` out of the scope of the `wss.on` and into `array`?

I've tried to use `array.push()` but obviously it didn't work. Any help and links to required reading on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you think is "messy" is THE correct way to do it.  Nest it.  If you really want to, you can put the insert in a separate function and call it from sindie the interval.  Async timing is only valid inside the async callback so that's where you do your work.  You could put `data` into a higher scoped array and store it there, but the timing of when a value was just added to the array is ONLY known inside the `setInterval()` callback.

Comment: Thank you! Was planning on wrapping my insert in a function and doing it that way if all else failed. Just wanted to make sure there was a more efficient way of doing it before I attempted it.

Answer (score 1):

Making my comment into an answer since it appears to be what you were looking for.

What you think is "messy" is THE correct way to do it. Nest it. If you really want to, you can put the insert in a separate function and call it from inside the interval. Async timing is only valid inside the async callback so that's where you do your work. You could put data into a higher scoped array and store it there, but the timing of when a value was just added to the array is ONLY known inside the `setInterval()` callback.

Comment: This probably sounds stupid, but if I didn't need to know the timing of when the value to the array. How do I pass data to a higher scoped array, so that other parts of my app can use those values generated?

Comment: @Jambo - You can `.push()` the data or otherwise assign it into higher scoped variables and it will be there in that higher scope.  You just won't know when you can use it from the higher scope unless you also have some sort of notification system: callback, eventEmitter, promise, etc...  Usually, when people new to node.js attempt to do this, they are making a programming mistake because they don't understand async timing.

Comment: So have been messing around with promises, callbacks and functions in order to try and get my desired results and have failed miserably (also if this question shouldnt be here please let me know). At the moment my single Node script is serving a user a webpage, then using a websocket and set interval pushing data out every second, should I split it into two scripts? one which receives data from the websocket server and then inserts it into my mongoDB every one minute and 5 minutes? or should i handle that on the client side with my html page? Im fairly new to asynchronous programming apologies